# SASS: How do I prepend every rule in a stylsheet with a selector to 'namespace'

Tags: namespaces, sass

I want to include new SASS in an old codebase. How do I avoid the new styles from leaking - given the new styles already written.

e.g.

```
.box
  width: 100%
  // ...

.tab
  display: inline-block
  &:active
    font-weight: bold

// Many more rules
```

to

```
.sandbox 
 .box
    width: 100%
    // ...
 .tab
    display: inline-block
    &:active
      font-weight: bold
 // .many .more .rules
```

This would be over many rules.

So the new html snippets in the old codebase would have

```
<div class="sandbox">
  <div class="box">
   <!-- Content here -->
  </div>
```

Or - is there an easier way of avoiding css code leakage?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  You seem to understand the concept of nesting, so the solution should be obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is obvious:

```
.sandbox {
    @import "foo";
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's obvious, but it's certainly elegant, and does work, thanks.

Comment: Basically how I do it as well. But it seems to be a problem when you work with @extend within `foo`.
It adds `.sandbox` twice to the selector. Not sure how to get around that at the moment.

Comment: This doesn't work if the imported file has selectors that use an ampersand anywhere other than the front of the rule. E.g. `.box { color: red; .theme-green & { color: green; } }`. Here, output will be `.sandbox .box { color: red; } .theme-green .sandbox .box { color: green; }` where ideally `.sandbox` should be outside `.theme-green`.